# File readeable on computer, but not on USB

Tags: usb

I just have A REALLY BIG PROBLEM. I've made a pdf file, and on my pc is readeable, and on others pc (I've send link to download to others) but, when i put it on my USB flashdrive it's not readeable anymore.

Please, what`s the matter...?

Thank you!

Comment: please add some more info. Which error is the one you got when trying to open the file? With which program? Can you send details about the file? (For example, `ls -l file.pdf` and `file file.pdf` when it's readable and when it's not... really too little info to be able to help.

Comment: Compress the pdf file and copy it to flash.

Comment: on windows it says that it's corrupt file, on ubuntu it loads for hours. When my pc, it opens, and on others (only if I put it for download).